# samba VFS module

Tags: linux, samba

I'm a newbie to samba development; with the current assignment I want to design a VFS layer for Samba. I want to trap some basic file operations and direct it to APIs supported by a custom library. I was following vfs_ceph as an example; but it seems with current samba-4.1 codebase; sources3/Makefile.in and sources3/configure.in are no longer distributed. Can someone share how a new module needs to be added with latest samba release.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, with the new release you need to update only one file source3/wscript.