# How to add new samba vfs module to build

Tags: samba, vfs

I know this question was asked here: [samba VFS module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956567/samba-vfs-module) but that answer doesn't seem to work for me, so I'm wondering if something's changed...

I'm working with source from the 4.1.6 tree and I've added a new vfs module file (under source3/modules), then (using vfs_full_audit.c as the example) I updated source3/wscript and then ran make (at the top level) as suggested.  The new module was not built.  Then (again using vfs_full_audit.c as the example) I updated source3/modules/wscript_build.  Still no luck getting my module to build.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
$ make clean
$ make distclean

$ ./configure   or $ ./configure.developer

Then
$ make
Lastly, if you want to install
$ sudo make install
```

Note: If you change wscript or wscript_build , you have to run ./configure again that is the trick